# What format/encoding is the Dovecot Diffie-Helman params file?

Tags: ssl, dovecot, openssl, centos8

I'm stuck on Dovecot 2.2.x because 2.3 package isn't available yet for CentOS 8.x, and I don't want to custom build in this use case.  Further, I'm bootstrapping this machine in order to snapshot it and launch many from the image.

One important step in getting Dovecot running the first time is allowing it to generate its own DHParams file (specifying an existing one doesn't come until 2.3).  This process takes a  LONG time on a low resource machine, so my goal is to either generate them remotely on another more powerful machine, or symlink to one generated locally that uses a quicker method in openssl based on different primes.

As per the docs, the dh params file generated by Dovecot is located at:

```
/var/lib/dovecot/ssl-parameters.dat
```

The issue I'm facing is, any dh params I've generated before come in the PEM format, but the one generated internally by Dovecot is NOT in PEM format.... can anyone tell me what format it is, and if it's possible to create it using openssl?

I haven't found any reference to the DH params format in any dovecot documentation, maybe because it was changed in 2.3, there wasn't a big need to document it?